# pandas.qcut returning NaN values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prnua.png)

I want to make a new column from "TotalPrice" with qcut function but some values returns as NaN. I don't know why?

I tried to change the data type of the column. But nothing has changed.

Comment: In the previous question (you deleted), there was a problem: there is a white space at the beginning of the words. **7Seeds** and ** 7Seeds** .please pay attention to this. @Kadir Can Üzümcü

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
you are doing a cqut on df rather than rfm dataframe. Ensure that this is what you expect to be doing

*Because you did not provide some data to build a minimal reproducible example, I would **guess** that there's not enough data or too many repeated values. Then, the underlying quartile function may fail to find the edge of the quantile and returns NaN*

(this did not make any sense because  "M" buckets did not make sense with "TotalPrice")

Comment: len(rfm) is 2893. I think there are enough data. I checked with boxplot. There are many outliers. But the biggest and the smallest values are not NaN. Only random values.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Looking at it closely, M labels do not make sense according to TotalPrice value. I think I will delete my answer

Comment: Do `df.groupby('M')['TotalPrice'].mean()` makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I noticed it now. I'm using wrong dataset hahahhaha